# How we can create android simulator without android studio for windows to launch flutter app in visual studio code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I need to launch a flutter app in an android emulator.I successfully launched the flutter in vscode.But when creating the emulator, it says

Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for null.

why is this...

Comment: you don't need android studio.  There are multiple emulators out there and even the android studio ones can be launced manually.  I suggest you get the microsoft one though.  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Comment: Try any other emulator like genymotion emulator.

Comment: I had the same issue - I wrote instructions in another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869002/315168