# "Invalid Argument(s): Cannot find executable for null" when emulated Android on VS Code - Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, flutter, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

When I try to emulate Android on VS Code in Mac OS Catalina after installing Android SDK by Android Studio it returns the message: Invalid Argument(s): Cannot find executable for null.
I have already created the environments variables ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME both pointing for the same directory: /Users/anderson/Library/Android/sdk but I have no success.

flutter doctor diagnostic:

anderson@MacBook-Pro-de-Anderson ~ % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266,
    locale en-BR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
anderson@MacBook-Pro-de-Anderson ~ %

Comment: You dont have a device emulator installed. You need to have a device installed in order to run it in the emulator

Comment: I have a ADV from Android Emulator but I can't create a emulator from VS Code. Therefore I cannot use my device for testing.

Comment: try reinstalling the avd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error both through command line `flutter emulator --create flutteremu` or using *Flutter: Launch Emulator* in Visual Studio Code.

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for null.".
```

You get this error despite `flutter doctor` telling you that everything is in order.

There is a log file, which details the error [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57483).

If you dig deeper you fill find out that the following Android command line tool does not work:

```sh
avdmanager
```

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

Boo hoooooooo. So despite the fact that Android SDK is full of Java, you still need to install a separate Java just to run some command-line commands.
Android SDK might not work if you have a wrong version of Java installed. Here is one good known version installed through Homebrew:

```sh
# Install Java 8 and Android SDK
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions

# See details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61521063/315168
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Check that Java works now:

```sh
java -version
```

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Now in your shell make sure you have all correct environment variables.

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

And then run `avdmanager` again:

```sh
avdmanager list
```

And now you should be able to launch emulator with Flutter support:

```sh
flutter emulator --create flutteremu
```

```
No suitable Android AVD system images are available. You may need to install these using sdkmanager, for example:
  sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

So let's install the images:

```sh
sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

And now Flutter should be able to launch an emulator:

```sh
flutter emulator --create flutteremu
```

And finally it will work:

```sh
Emulator 'flutter_emulator' created successfully.
```

Close any running Visual Studio Code.
Start Visual Studio Code from shell and explicitly set the environment variables for VSCode process:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
code
```

And now *Flutter: Launch Emulator* works.

[image]